# Project authority level

Tags: project-management-style, software, authority

There are 2 major systems operated in an organization (an ERP and another major operational application) which are handled by 2 project managers. Data flows from the operational application to ERP. A new major request comes from client end to the project manager who manages the operational application to develop a module which will require an integration to transfer data from the operational application to ERP and once data is passed, there are certain changes that will need to be modifed from ERP end in order to complete the requirement.

My question is, should both project managers be responsible / accountable for the entire project where the operational application project manager handles until the completion of data transferring from operational application to ERP and the ERP project manager has to take care of the ERP end modification? Or else, should the operational application project manager be solely responsible for the entire project? And if it's the first scenario where both project managers are responsible, should the client be informed about the project authority level or does it need to be handled internally?

Extremely sorry if the question is too long or complex

Comment: Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

CLIENT ?!? This isn't rocket science...

The client should have one major contact in your company through which all issues could be addressed. That contact would have authority over both project managers and that contact should decide how your company is going to support the client. You may for instance need a third project manager over the other two. You absolutely cannot have two different project managers passing the buck between themselves. The client should absolutely not see any internal squabbles. Your are to solve the client's problems, the client isn't suppose to referee your internal teams.

Likewise your company should have one major point of contact in the client's company to handle issues. So if two different folks in the client's company want the opposite result, then your company has someone to whom they can escalate the problem.